# Edit/Modify & Delete of record from a Random Access File in C

Tags: c, file, updating, random-access

The program should modify or delete a specific record according to employee id, in modifying part it writes the modified record as a new one at the end of the file, the deleting part works only once and then give me a segmentation fault.

Modifying:

How can I modify the code to rewrite the edited record in the same position?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

struct record_em{
    int id;
    char name[20];
    int salary;
    int age;
};

int main( void )
{
    struct record_em employee;
    FILE *fp;
    int n;
    int ch;
    fp = fopen("empRecord.dat","rb+");

    printf("Enter Id Number:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    rewind(fp);
    while (!feof(fp)){

        fscanf(fp,"%d %s %d %d", &employee.id, employee.name, &employee.salary, &employee.age);

        if (employee.id==n){
            printf("%d %s %d %d \n",employee.id, employee.name, employee.salary,employee.age);
            printf("\n Do you want to change the name ?\n");
            scanf("%d",&ch);

            if (ch==1){
                printf("Enter new name:\n");
                scanf("%s",employee.name);
            }
            printf("\n Do you want to change the salary ?(y/n)\n");
            scanf("%d",&ch);

            if ( ch==2 ){
                printf("Enter new salary:\n");
                scanf("%d",&employee.salary);
            }
            printf("\n Do you want to change the age ?(y/n)\n");
            scanf("%d",&ch);

            if ( ch==3 ){
                printf("Enter new age:\n");
                scanf("%d",&employee.age);
            }
            fseek(fp,-sizeof(employee),SEEK_CUR);
            fprintf(fp, "%d %s %d %d\n", employee.id, employee.name, employee.salary, employee.age);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    printf("Record Not Found \n");
    return 0;
}
```

Deleting:

How can I modify the code to make it delete records as many times as I want?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct record_em{
    int id;
    char name[20];
    int salary;
    int age;
};

int main()
{
    struct record_em employee;
    FILE *fp, *ft;
    int n;
    fp = fopen("empRecord.dat","r");
    ft = fopen("Temp.dat","wb+");

    printf("\nEnter ID of employee to delete ");

    scanf("%d",&n);
    rewind(fp);
    while (!feof(fp)){
        fscanf(fp,"%d %s %d %d", &employee.id, employee.name, &employee.salary,  &employee.age);

        if(employee.id!=n){
            fprintf(ft, "%d %s %d %d\n", employee.id, employee.name, employee.salary, employee.age);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(ft);
    remove("empRecord.dat");
    rename("Temp.dat","EempRecord.dat");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can save the offset of information block and overwrite the changed data from that offset.Check fseek().

Comment: @tAmirNaghizadeh Um. no he can't. This record definition, though fixed in the `struct` of his code, is variant by how he is writing it to disk (because it is text translation). Make the string-representation of *any* of those fields larger than the prior, and you're overwriting data in at least one subsequent record.

Comment: Right..,Since record separated by newline , he can use `strcmp()` on first recode in each line reported by `getline()`.

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto im trying to avoid using them because its something new that i do not take it in this course, i will try to use binary files, if they do not work well i will use the formatted file, Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the Key point of code:

```
void update(char filename[],char name[])
{
    int records=0;
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename,"rb+");
    while(fread(&st,sizeof(st),1,fp)==1)
    {
         if(strcmp(name,st.name)==0)
         {
              printf("\nEnter new name: ");
              scanf("%s",st.name);
              printf("\nEnter new roll no.: ");
              scanf("%d",&st.roll);
              fseek(fp,sizeof(struct student)*records,SEEK_SET);//This is key line..
              fwrite(&st,sizeof(st),1,fp);
         }
         records++; // in the while loop...
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Below is the structure of student:

```
struct student{
     int roll;
     char name[20];
}st;
```

This is the general method to modify/update the record. You can use same syntax for your employee structure.

Answer (score 1):

It's not good to manipulate a binary file using the C functions that are intended to be used to manipulate text files fprintf.

For example, in your code I see:

```
fseek(fp,-sizeof(employee),SEEK_CUR);
fprintf(fp, "%d %s %d %d\n", employee.id, employee.name, employee.salary, employee.age);
```

This will bring you problems, since you are traveling within your file as a binary file to then write characters on it.  You shoud use the fwrite function instead.

My recommendation: check your whole program, define your persistence strategy and be consistent with this.

Comment: when i use fwrite i can not have a plain text file

Comment: @fatimah It is the variability of the text-content of your values that is making this task a bigger chore than it needs to be. Using a fixed binary record length would make scanning records, modifying them in-place, and marking them as deleted *trivial*.

Comment: @WhozCraig i will try to use a fixed binary record and see what will happen :) ,, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I think here is your problem, first you have a minus sign before the `sizeof`it's a bit weird to see that, and second the `SEEK_CUR` makes you move further than your current file is so take a look here [fseek(), rewind()](http://beej.us/guide/bgc/output/html/multipage/fseek.html)

```
fseek(fp,-sizeof(employee),SEEK_CUR); //This is not the definitive read below.
         ^------minus symbol.  ^------- the type of seek.
```

I recommend You to do some modifications:

1. Use a common `Formatted File` to make your life easier, remember "The perfection is the simplicity".
2. Use `SEEK_SET` to use the relative position from the beginning of the file, second use the `struct's size` as the parameter for `sizeof`.

   ```
   fseek( fp, sizeof( struct record_em), SEEK_SET );
   ```
3. Use the `member` id as the key of your sink and use a consecutive series of numbers, but obviously you should have created a file with 100, 1000 employers.

   ```
   1 Andrew 20000 27
   ^   ^      ^    ^_____ age 
   |   |      |__________ salary ( I would have used double here)
   |   |_________________ name
   |_____________________ id ( Key for the relative position from the beginning)
   ```
4. You will have to change your mind, and when you imagine "delete" a record you will write a white space (with exception of the key) example Imagine that the poor Andrew was fired and you will delete his record.

   ```
   1 "Empty space"   0   0
   ^       ^         ^   ^______ age (0 = nothing)
   |       |         |__________ salary (0 = nothing)
   |       |____________________ name ("" = nothing)
   |____________________________ id ( Key for the relative position from the beginning)
   ```

PD:currently adding more information.

Comment: The OP's use of `fseek(fp,-sizeof(employee),<<anything>>);`
to "rewind" is completely wrong. He is using variable-length "records" by writing their "text" content using unframed (no fixed widths) formatted output and input. `1 Al 25000 20\n` is nowhere near the length of `12345 Washington 125000 42\n`, yet that is how his "records" are represented. Moving around by increments of `sizeof(employee)` would make sense if he were using fixed records, **but he is *not***. This makes the job of finding, modifying, and deleting a specific record by `id` a major undertaking.

Answer (score 1):

```
SEEK_CUR
```

offset is relative to the current file pointer position. So, in effect, you can say, "Move to my current position plus 30 bytes," or, "move to my current position minus 20 bytes."
eg. `fseek(fp, -30, SEEK_CUR)`
ref. http://beej.us/guide/bgc/output/html/multipage/fseek.html

I don't think he is wrong in using the negative of the `sizeof()` function.
But you would be better off using the `sizeof(struct record_em)` instead!